# No me cargan los post de un usuario en espesifico

Tags: php, pdo

Hola tengo un problema quiero cargar los post de un usuario en especifico pero este mismo me muestra todos los post (post de todos los usuarios)

Mi meta es que en el perfil del usuario se muestre las publicaciones que hizo ese usuario en concreto
este es mi script

```php
<?php
session_start();
$profile = $_SESSION['profile'];
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=remotemysql.com;dbname=;charset=utf8mb4',"","");
$sql = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM post WHERE usuario=$profile');
$sql->execute();

while ($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo '<div class="post-container">
    <div class="post">
      <div class="panel panel-white panel-shadow">
        <!--header-->
        <div class="post-heading">
          <div class="pull-left image">';
          echo '<a href="/'.$username.'">';
          echo '<img src="img/avatar/'.$result['avatar'].'?>" id="updateImage-64402" class="avatar" alt="'.$username.'profile picture">';
          echo '
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="meta">
            <div class="title">';
            echo '<span> <a href="/'.$username.'">'.$username.'</a> </span>';
            echo '
            </div>
            <h6>';
            echo '<span class="time">'.$result['time_date_post'].'</span>';
            echo '</h6>
          </div>
        </div>';
        echo ';
        <div class="post-description">
          <p>'.$result['cuerpo'].'</p>';

          if ($result['image'] == "") {

          }else {
            echo 'div class="wo_shared_doc_file" id="fullsizeimg" style="display:none;">
              <img src="'.$result['image'].'" alt="image" class="image-file pointer" onclick="Wo_OpenLightBox(105588);">
            </div>';


          }
          echo '
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>';
}
?>
```

y esta es mi tabla de post en mi base de datos

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `cuerpo` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `avatar` varchar(2500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(3500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `video` varchar(3500) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_date_post` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

probé de muchas formas el tratar de solucionar el problema

usando un WHERE id en 'SELECT * FROM post WHERE usuario=$profile'
tambienun WHERE usuario pero no logro arreglarlo ademas trate con un $_GET['id']

Nota:La tabla de usuario y la tabla de post son independientes
lo único que comparten son los Nombres de usuario a la hora de que se publique un post

> Actualizo!

**Si hago una consulta me dice que** La cosulta 'Guest' en where clause es desconocida en mi tabla post si tengo un valor llamado Guest, con las id si funciona pero quiero que se filtre por usuario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Le muestra algo error el código que tiene actualmente?  En la conexión no pones la BD ¿y el servidor es el correcto? `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=remotemysql.com;dbname=;charset=utf8mb4',"","");`

Comment: @CobosDeyby todo es correcto me muestra todos los post sin error el problema es que no se filtran, tengo un perfil.php en donde se muestran los datos del usuario y en esta pagina quiero que se vean los post de ese usuario pero envés de mostrare los de ese usuario en particular me cargan todos los post

Comment: Verifica también que la variable sesión esté guardando un valor, la puedes imprimir para verificar su valor y por último en el SELECT hazlo así: `$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM post WHERE usuario = '$profile'");`

Comment: hum en el script user-post.php no me carga nada la pagina se queda en blanco, lo que es raro ya que en la pagina de inicio me carga todos los post

Comment: ahi vi el select: SELECT * FROM post WHERE usuario=$profile, bueno lo pirmero que haria seria ver que esta ingresando en $profile, asique correle un var_dump($profile); eso, para saber que esta ingresando en la query para comprar con el usuario

Comment: $sql = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM post WHERE usuario=$profile');

Comment: luego si tenes acceso a phpmyadmin, corre esa misma query ahi, hardcodeando el valor de $profile, seria algo asi, imaginemos: SELECT * FROM post WHERE usuario='pedro';

Comment: y en $profile que te llega? (hacele var_dump)

Comment: Basicamente, en estos casos, seria: 1) revisar la query sin condiciones SELECT * FROM post , que funcione bien, podes hacer esto en el panel de phpmyadmin si estas usando mysql 2) revisar que llega en la variable $profile, antes de ingresar a la query (var_dump) 3) revisar que la query y específicamente la condición WHERE usuario=$profile funciona ok con el valor que llega de $profile, esto también lo haces en phpmyadmin. 4) Si todo esta ok, ya deberías en este punto haber detectado el error en el código, felicidad total.

Comment: @rendor9 actualice mi post

Comment: Y esa columna `GUEST` existe en la tabla `posts` o esta ne otra?

Comment: >post>usuario>Guest si existe es un valor de usuario por ejemplo si filtro los post por >post>id>1 si funciona pero no por >post>usuario>Guest

Comment: es que `guest` lo esta interpretando como una columna que no encuentra, me parece tienes un error en el como estas visualizando tus columnas

Comment: bueno, te tenes que fijar que tipo de dato guarda la tabla post en al columna usuario. ¿es un texto? ¿es un numero?. Y revisar que la query sea acorde a eso, o sea, donde haces el where, por ejemplo WHERE usuario = 'alguntexto' (entre comillas!). Ese es el problema que creo estas teniendo, basicamente el where lo estas haciendo mal y el servidor de base de datos no entiende tu pregunta (tu query). Fijate mi respuesta, que puse ayer y segui los pasos (que para algo lo puse).

Comment: otro tema, no utilices un * en el select, por mas cómodo que sea hacerlo. Agrega bien los campos que tiene la tabla, escribirlos, tipo "select id,nombre,apellido, telefono from tabla..." para saber con que se esta trabajando. Sino uno esta a ciegas y cuando trabajas con desarrolladores de sistemas en un problema, es necesario que todo este claro y a la vista. (y aparte la consulta es mas rapida, ganas milisegundos). Aparte asi dejas en claro que el campo es usuario y no usuarios (con s final) , descartando cualquier error posible de sintaxis.